# How to return proper Http Response instead of JSON object

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I have a very simple Web API with only GET controller. Inside the get controller, I am reading an XML file, converting that XML file into a JSON object and returning it.

```
public JObject Get()
{
    //Read XML
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\myfile.xml");
    string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xDoc);
    JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);

    return json;              
}
```

I want to put the XML reading and JSON conversion lines into an exception handler and return **404 Error code** (or any proper code for this situation) if the XML file cannot be opened (or any other exception occurs). But since my return type id `JObject`, I am not able to return a proper http respose, so how can I do that?

Comment: Instead of JObject you can return an ActionResult. In case you find it you will return a JsonResult, otherwise HttpNotFound

Comment: As far as I know Action result is specifically for MVC and IHttpActionResult is more commonly used in web api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the return type of the Action Method to `IHttpActionResult` you can then do something like this

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    if (!File.Exists(@"D:\myfile.xml"))
        return NotFound();

    //Read XML
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\myfile.xml");
    string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xDoc);
    JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);
    return Ok(json);
}
```

This should give you the flexibility you are after.

**Quick Explanation of methods used**

`return OK(json)` will return a successful (HTTP 200) response with the serialised `json` in the body.

`return NotFound()` will result in a failed request and a HTTP 404 result.

For an error you should ideally return a 5xx code, which can be achieved with `return InternalServerError();`

For more information on these and other helpers in the `ApiController` base class, check out the [page on microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh834453(v=vs.118))

Comment: I think it's important to mention what Ok() does and what the OP can user for a 404 message (as they specifically asked for it).

Comment: @StormMuller: I thought that `404` is the proper code in this situation but please suggest if I should return something else ( updated my question).

Comment: Your question was clear. What I'm raising where is that the `Ok()` method returns a `200` status code and not a `404`status code. Which may or may not be what you intend to do. But the answer has been updated to include the `NotFound()` method which is what you need for the `404` status code.